# In Spock mocks impossible to verify mock against result: MissingPropertyException: No such property

Tags: groovy, mocking, spock

I have some strange error when trying to check mock in **then** block with the result returned by the tested method, which I don't know beforehand. Here is a simple example:

```
import spock.lang.Specification

class MockingTest extends Specification {

    private MyListener listener = Mock()

    def 'test listener called'() {
        when:
        def service = new MyService(listener)
        def message = service.foo()
        then:
        1 * listener.onEvent(message)
    }

    class MyService {
        private MyListener listener;

        MyService(MyListener listener) {
            this.listener = listener
        }

        String foo() {
            String message = "Hello " + new Random().nextInt(10);
            listener.onEvent(message)
            return message;
        }
    }

    class MyListener {
        void onEvent(String message) {
            System.out.println(message);
        }
    }
}
```

And the error is:

```
No such property: message for class: MockingTest
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: message for class: MockingTest
    at MockingTest.test listener called(MockingTest.groovy:14)
```

Event that

```
1 * listener.onEvent(message)
```

is placed in **then** block seems that Spock tries to initialize it early, even before **when** block is executed.

Is it any way to work around it, and check that mock is called with some local variable, not a constant?
The thing which is very simple to do with java + mockito appears to be very complex with Spock :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use capture technique for this purpose, where you capture the first argument (`it[0]`) of the `onEvent` method call and assign it into pre-declared variable (`capturedMessage`):

```
def 'test listener called'() {
    given:
    def service = new MyService(listener)
    String capturedMessage = null
    when:
    def message = service.foo()
    then:
    1 * listener.onEvent(_) >> { capturedMessage = it[0] as String }
    message == capturedMessage
}
```

The problem in your example is that the interaction test (`1 * listener.onEvent(message)`) is executed before the `foo()` call is finished and then the `message` variable is not declared yet.

Side note: `given` is the right section for declaring and initialization of test data like the `service`.